# MySQL: How to efficiently count the number of rows in a large table?

Tags: mysql

What is the way to most efficiently count the total number of rows in a large table? I have a table with 23 million rows and the following query takes 30+ seconds on production hardware:

```
select count(*) from tablename;
```

It seems that MySQL must be doing a table scan, but it doesn't seem like this should be necessary.

Comment: Do you have a primary key? What indexes are there on the table?

Comment: @Jacob, Does it really matter? The InnoDb will have to count 23mi PK's or indexes if they exist.

Comment: It is probably doing an index scan, but it will still be slow.

Comment: Do you always need an exact count? I think you can calculate an approximate count.

Answer (score 20):

If an approximation is enough, you can use:

```
show table status like 'tablename'
```

Comment: @Karolis: no. it is SHOW TABLE STATUS [FROM database] [LIKE 'pattern'].

Answer (score 3):

Row count of a table is slow in InnoDB.

MyISAM on the other hand have the row count as a property of the table, which makes your query really fast on MyISAM.

Comment: That's the price you pay for ACID compliance in InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Use cache query SELECT SQL_CACHE count(column_name) from table

Comment: The query cache is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.20, and is removed in MySQL 8.0.